# How can I find a value in a table via an another related value in that table?

Tags: java, database, jpa

I created a table in a Database, so I got a "customerId" in that table and a "cardId", so a Customer can has multiples cardId's . What I tried right now is that:

```
 public CustomerId getCustomerId(String cardId) {

        this.getEntityManager();
        return em.find(CustomerMappingHelper.class, customerId);
    }
```

even though this won't work (I guess since my Ecplise shows me some Errors) ......furthermore I have in an another class a lookup methode, right now I stuck because I'm not sure how I can look up after a customer Id through an another card Id, just the logic behind that to look in that row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used JPQL and solved my Problem, here I search the customerId through the cardId

```
public String getCustomerId(String cardId) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c.customerId FROM CustomerMapping c WHERE c.cardId = :cardId");
    q.setParameter("cardId", cardId);
    String customerId = (String) q.getSingleResult();
    return customerId;
```